# Problems in creating an instance from a .class file

Tags: java, client-server

I am working on a client server application wherein i copy a .class file from one jvm to another. I need to create an instance using this .class file in the second machine (this machine doesn't contain its .java file) using reflections but i receive the following error. Further my project consists of various packages - one for the server and another for the client. While using reflections, I try to supply just the class name (copied class) which makes me wonder if that is an issue. Could there be an issue with the class path or not supplying the fully qualified class name or something else?

```
java  Server/remoteServer
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Server/Registry_stub (wrong name: registry/Registry_stub)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at generics.Naming.bind(Naming.java:34)
    at Server.remoteServer.main(remoteServer.java:17)
```

This is the method where i am experiencing problems:

```
    public static void bind(String name, myRemoteInterface obj) throws AlreadyBoundException, RemoteException, IOException {

    RegistryInterface stub = null;
     try{

         stub = (RegistryInterface)Class.forName("Server.Registry_stub").newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
            | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    stub.bind(name, obj);

}
```

The Registry_stub in compiled in a different machine and the .class file is copied to the client machine where the bind function is called (in a package called Server). My aim here is to call the bind method defined in the Registry_stub class for which I have the .class in the client.

Thank you for your help

Comment: That is interesting question, but without seeing your code we could only guess how exactly you are handling storing and sending `.class` file.

Comment: When you send `.class` file do you send its full-package-name? Do you store it in `foo/bar/YourClass.class` structure inside directory from your classpath so classloader could find it? Can we see code which handles writing send class?

Comment: I actually have not sent the file using code. I have just copied the compiled .class file straight to the Server folder of the second machine using scp. I guess this is where iam wrong. Iam mainting the structure I use Class.forName(Server.Registry_stub) and I copy the Registry_stub.class file to the Server package folder.

Comment: Did you include folder which contains `Server` folder into classpath?

Comment: Yes, iam still facing the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't post any code I am not sure if this is actually your problem but here it goes.

---

Information about package is also written in class file. I base this assumption on fact that there is reflective method `getPackage()` which returns package. Example

```
System.out.println(String.class.getPackage().getName());
```

will print `java.laang`.

To be able to load send class you will have to use its full-package-name, in other words `Class.forName("foo.bar.YourClass")` and class ClassLoader will try to search for `YourClass.class` file inside directories representing package so this structure must be placed inside (`[...]` represents directory)

```
[foo]
  |
  +-[bar]
      |
      +-YourClass.class
```

structure (`foo` directory must be placed inside directory specified in classpath).

So create some directory in your project for such package structures and add it to your class path. Also don't forget to not only send name of file but instead full-package-name.

Answer (score 0):

When loading a class, you are always using some class loader. In your case, I would use a fresh class loader, having access to the copied .class file, and make sure you use that class loader when attempting to load the class.

To get more detailed help, you have to give more context. With just the stack trace you supplied it is very hard to help you in a more specific way.